Drawing and animating a 3d character with no face
Alsalamulaikm, i wanted to know if i can make a 3d character on my computer for example exactly like spiderman that has no facial features but it does have some goggles or eyes but they are not completely eyes its something to see through, you know what i mean. Is it haram? If it is not haram, can i animate it? Like can i make it move and jump? if it is haram because of the eyes, what if i remove the eyes aswell and it’s completely faceless, is it haram then?
